# Data always null when posting JSON from Android to C# WebAPI

Tags: java, c#, android

I have the following WebAPI written in C#:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private IActorSystemShell _actorSystem;

    public UserController(IActorSystemShell actorSystem)
    {
        _actorSystem = actorSystem;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddUser")]
    public async Task AddUser(User user)
    {
        var response = await _actorSystem.EntryPoint
            .Ask<SystemMessages.RequestResponse>(UserMessages.DynamicUserRequestNoResponse
                .Instance(_ => { _.Add(user); }), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        if (response.Result.HttpResponseCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(response.Result.HttpResponseCode,
                response.Result.ErrorMessage));
    }
}
```

From my android application, I am trying to add a user, by calling this C# WebAPI. Here is the relevant code in Android:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(PostParams... postParam) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try{
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) postParam[0].getmUrl().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);

        //we know it is if of type user
        User userData = (User)postParam[0].getmPostObject();
        String userJsondata = userData.toJsonString();

        //get writing stream
        OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        outWriter.write(userJsondata);

        //get response
        int httpResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){
        //log
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //log
    }
    finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When the breakpoint in C# is hit, the value of User received is always null.  Why is this happening?

Here is the `User.java` class:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {

public User() {

}

private String _name = "";
@Bindable
public String get_name() {
    return _name;
}
public void set_name(String _name) {
    this._name = _name;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._name);
}

private String _surname = "";
@Bindable
public String get_surname() {
    return _surname;
}
public void set_surname(String _surname) {

    this._surname = _surname;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._surname);
}

private String _email = "";
@Bindable
public String get_email() {
    return _email;
}
public void set_email(String _email) {

    this._email = _email;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._email);
}

public String toJsonString(){
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jObject.put("Name", get_name());
        jObject.put("Surname", get_surname());
        jObject.put("Email", get_email());
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d("Error", "User.toJson");
    }
    return jObject.toString();
}
```

}

And here is the `User.cs` class.

```
public class User : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After adding `flush()` to OutputStreamWriter, I now no longer get a null object on the C# server side, but an object who's properties are null.

I have updated the code as follow:

```
//get writing stream
        OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        outWriter.write(userJsondata);
        outWriter.flush();
```

Just FYI, when I debug and check the value for `userJsonData`, I can see that my properties are properly set to whats given from the input fields

Comment: I assume the value of `userJsondata` is correct? What does your c# `User` class look like? If you change the controller method to accept `object` instead, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to successfully post data to my C# WebAPI.  Here is my updated code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(PostParams... postParam) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try{
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) postParam[0].getmUrl().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);

        //we know it is if of type user
        User userData = (User)postParam[0].getmPostObject();
        String userJsondata = userData.toJsonString();

        //get writing stream
        OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        outWriter.write(userJsondata);
        outWriter.flush();

        //get response
        int httpResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){
        //log
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //log
    }
    finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I changed was, I added the content type in the header of the request, as follow:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

And I flushed the OutputStreamWriter after writing the data to the OuputStream, as follow:

```
outWriter.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when the posted object was too big. In my case, I was using IIS Express for local development. On our testing environment using IIS I couldn't reproduce it.

Did you try to use Fiddler or any other tool to mimic the same request?

Comment: The class contains 3 properties, Name, Surname, Email, I doubt the posted object is too big in this case

Comment: And did you also try any other client (e. g. Fiddler) except your application?